# Remove html tag except img src and a href

Tags: regex, oracle, replace

How can i remove html tag in string except img src and a href. I tried as followed but it removes all of tag.

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE('lorem <em>ipsum</em><img src="/folder/file.jpg" /> ipsum','<.*?>') 
FROM DUAL;
```

Result : lorem ipsum (I need like this lorem /folder/file.jpg ipsum)

Comment: So you don't just need to remove the tags, you also need to remove what's between them? In your example, you deleted <em>ipsum</em>, including the word ipsum between the <em> and </em> tags, not just the tags themselves.

Comment: @mathguy No,he didnt't, due to non-greedy matching within angular brackets.

Comment: @collapsar - I asked a question about the REQUIREMENT, so the answer can't be related to any solution. Look at his last sentence, in parentheses, where he shows the answer he WANTS.

Comment: @mathguy Yep, you are right. Embarassing as it is, I stopped reading after the query ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to protect the contents of the `<img` tag's `src` and the `<a` tag's `href` attribute against deletion. The following regex preserves only these parts of html tags in the original data:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (
    REGEXP_REPLACE (
        REGEXP_REPLACE (
            'lorem <a class="interference" href="http://www.example.com"><em>ipsum</em><img src="/folder/file.jpg" /> ipsum</a> whatever'
          , '<a[^>]*? href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>|<img[^>]*? src="([^"]+)"[^>]*>|<a[^>]*? href=''([^'']+)''[^>]*>|<img[^>]*? src=''([^'']+)''[^>]*>'
          , '<<\1\2>>'
        )
      , '([^<])<[^<][^>]*>'
      , '\1'
    )
  , '<<([^>]+)>>'
  , ' \1 '
)
```

***Explanation***

- The attribute values to be protected are wrapped in double angular brackets: `<<`, `>>`.
  The match allows for interfering attributes between the tag name and the target attribute and for attribute values delimited either by double or by single quotes.
- The target attribute is either enclose by single quotes or by double quotes. Thus, in every match, exactly 1 capture group will be filled. Thus the sequence of both of them may be inserted in the substituting pattern `'<<\1\2>>'` without any further disambiguation logic.
- All character sequences wrapped in single angular brackets are replaced
- Removal of the double angular brackets `<<`, `>>`.

***Caveats***

- In general, it is **strongly discouraged to use regexen as a substitute for proper parsing**. It is much more error-prone and much less flexible and extensible; a nightmare to maintain and debug.
- The match does not allow for escaped double quotes in the target attribute values.
  This should not be an issue for `src` and `href`; however, expect to run into troubles for target attributes like `title` or `data-...`
- The substitutions should not interfere with data in literals, since `<` and `>` need to be represented as entities in html unless being used as syntax elements. However, this would not hold for xhtml data with cdata sections, where occurrences of would be lost `<<`, `>>`. If that might be an issue, test the original string for occurrences.

**Supplement**

In case you wish to preserve the said attribute values in valid markup, protect the tags with the target attributes. To this end, use the following:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (
    REGEXP_REPLACE (
        REGEXP_REPLACE (
            'lorem <a href="http://www.example.com"><em>ipsum</em><img src="/folder/file.jpg" /> ipsum</a> whatever'
          , '(<a href|<img src|</a|</img)'
          , '<\1'
        )
      , '([^<])<[^<][^>]*>'
      , '\1'
    )
  , '<(<a href|<img src|</a|</img)'
  , '\1'
)
```

***Explanation***

- The tags to be protected are prefixed by an additional `<`.
- All tags that do not start with a double `<<` are replaced
- Backsubstitution of the `<<` sequence.
  The substitution is applied in the same contexts as the prefixing

***Caveats***

- The general caveat still holds: **better do not use regexen as a stand-in for parsers**.
- In order to keep the result being valid html, matching start and end tags need to be preserved. Unfortunately this matching cannot be accounted for using oracle regexp faclities (and is very complicated with other regex engines that do support recursion). Thus, *all* closing `a` and `img` tags are kept.

While the latter rarely occurs in the wild (unless it is xhtml), the former will cause problems for `<a name="...` tags.

- Tags with interfering attributes between the element name and the target attributes will be deleted. Most commonly this would apply to `class` or `data-` attributes. Catering for this case makes the regex more complicated again due to the 4 supported variations ( tag names `a`/`img`, single/double quote delimiters ) and potential interfering attributes:

--

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (
    REGEXP_REPLACE (
        REGEXP_REPLACE (
            REGEXP_REPLACE(
                  'lorem <a href="http://www.example.com"><em>ipsum</em><img src="/folder/file.jpg" /> ipsum</a> whatever'
                , '</(a|img)>'
                , '<</\1>'
            )
          , '<(a )[^>]*?(href="[^"]+"|href=''[^'']+'')[^>]*>|<(img )[^>]*?(src="[^"]+"|src=''[^'']+'')[^>]*>'
          , '<<\1\2\3\4>'
        )
      , '([^<])<[^<][^>]*>'
      , '\1'
    )
  , '<(<a href|<img src|</a|</img)'
  , '\1'
)
```